# Is there a cryptographic scheme that allows joint encryption using a shared secret?

Tags: encryption, secret-sharing

I'm looking for a type of algorithm that could be used to encrypt text with a shared secret $S$. What I would like to have is the secret to be broken up in three pieces, where any combination of two pieces can be used to reconstruct shared key $S$ in order to decrypt the text.

Is there any mathematical or cryptographic scheme of approaching this? Physically breaking up shared secret $S$ is one approach but what about others?

Comment: There is an obvious lousy way which costs a factor of $n\choose k$ ciphertext expansion—in this case, $k = 2$, $n = 3$.  Specifically, you can encrypt it independently three times using a 2-of-2 scheme where the ciphertext is $C_{ij} = P \oplus S_i \oplus S_j$ for each $i < j$.  Here, of course, we can compute $S_i = \operatorname{AES}_{k_i}(0) \mathbin\Vert \operatorname{AES}_{k_i}(1) \mathbin\Vert \cdots$ for efficient storage of the secret.  But that ciphertext storage cost is rather unsatisfying.  (Also you should consider authentication.)

Answer (score 1):

The common procedure for what's asked is to draw a random key $S$, use it to encipher the plaintext using a symmetric cipher such as AES-CTR, then split the key into so-called key shares per a threshold scheme, so that $k=2$ shares out of $n=3$ are required to reconstruct the key. A generic $(k,n)$ threshold scheme is [Shamir Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).

Here is a very simple $(2,3)$ threshold scheme: each bit $x$ of the key is splits into three shares values $a$, $b$, $c$. Share value $a$ is chosen uniformly at random among $\{0,1,2\}$, then the other two are determined as $b=(a+x)\bmod3$, $c=(b+x)\bmod3$ (where $\bmod3$ designates subtracting $3$ from the result if it is $3$ or more). For decoding, if any two share values among $a$, $b$, $c$ are equal, then the corresponding key bit $x$ was $0$; otherwise it was $1$. Demonstrably, a single share gives no clue about the key. See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52289/555) for schemes still workable by hand and giving a slightly more compact encoding.

As pointed in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54024/555#comment119546_54026), this has the drawback that who/whatever draws, uses and/or splits $S$ could be dishonest, keep $S$, and decipher the plaintext.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to do this _without_ just splitting up the secret $S$.  In particular, can we do it without granting one trusted party/computer unilateral access to the secret, so that decryption of the message _always_ requires participation of two of the three parties?  For n-of-n, it's easy, of course, but for k-of-n when k < n I don't have an easy answer before tea time.